# Ошибка System.Int32[]

Tags: c#

У меня, когда программа скомпилирована (программа для консоли), выдает в консоли `System.Int32[]`. При любом коде выбивает это значение, на других компьютерах программа работает нормально.

В чем проблема?

Программирую на С#.

**Обновление**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string s = "Сегодня мы с вами рассмотрели, как работать со строками в Си-шарп. Были описаны основные операторы и методы, которые используются для работы со строками";

    string res = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("Были"), Convert.ToInt32( s.IndexOf(", которые") - s.IndexOf("Были")));
    Console.WriteLine(res);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: @Renneur приведите код вашей программы, чтобы можно было сказать что-то определенное.

Comment: Просто уточнить: а платформа, для которой скомпилирована программа (.net framework 4.5.1 для visual studio 2013 по-умолчанию) установлена? Она, кстати, не работает под xp...

Comment: @Renneur, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.

Comment: @Expert, вы удивитесь, но автор вопроса использует именно кириллицу

Comment: @Renneur, Также язык форума русский. Перепишите ваш вопрос, иначе нам придется его удалить.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` - это-то зачем в коде? Хотя к вопросу это не относится.

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, не вижу проблем в вашем коде - у меня он также работает корректно. Если у вас действительно есть какие-то проблемы с кодом, то могу лишь предположить, что причиной тому могут быть локальные языковые настройки. Попробуйте заменить третью строку вашего кода на следующую:

```
string res = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("Были", StringComparison.Ordinal), Convert.ToInt32(s.IndexOf(", которые", StringComparison.Ordinal) - s.IndexOf("Были", StringComparison.Ordinal)));
```

Comment: Не работает, выдает то же самое `System.Int32[]`.

Comment: а вы точно уверены, что запускаете именно этот код? Все-таки чудес и магии в программировании не бывает, поэтому ваша проблема скорее всего кроется в чем-то очень простом

Comment: Я запускал разные проекты с разными кодами, а выбивает одно и то же.